# HTML, need advice on using grid to design a "1 page" website

Tags: html, css, grid

Well since i am using a websocket, I am limited to one webpage, but in this web page I am going to create a lot of sections to act like pages, the main control for the web page will be using gestures detected by the xbox kinect, the web page itself is going to act like a navigation GUI.

So for example, I have 6 main pages, lets say I swipe either left or right to navigate, then I swipe up or down to go to the "sub pages" for the main page, which will actually redirect them to the appropriate section

[pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bohTs.png)
as seen in the image, each section will be the main "page" e.g. page 3...
so when I swipe down it will go to 3.1 if I swipe up it will go to 3.3.
using the grid will make it more organised, or I could just arrange them randomly and redirect the user to the appropriate page? for example if I do not make it more organised i could just have a 6x2 grid (maybe?) which contain all the pages and I redirect them appropriately

Answer (score 0):

This jQuery based library has what you are looking for:

http://www.zehfernandes.com/jquery.fullContent/#home